# Copy/paste charts from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, copy, powerpoint, paste

I have a worksheet ("Tile with chart") with 2 dropdown menus. User selects 1st dropdown (list of ministries) in cell H3, which then pulls list of KPI IDs (in cell I3). List of KPI IDs is sourced from M2 (it's changing list depending on number of KPIs, so source list is referenced as $M$2#). User can then select one of the KPI IDs in I3 which updates a chart (Chart 2) in the worksheet. What i am trying to do is for VBA code to mimic step 2 (i.e., VBA goes through KPI IDs). Each chart (Chart 2) needs to be copied and pasted to a slide (can be saved under ministry name (from H3).

I have a code that partially accomplishes this - user still needs to select each KPI ID, then click on button and chart is copied into powerpoint slide. I am not able however to achieve full requirement (i.e., VBA going through each KPI ID, copying each chart to same slide (without losing formatting, but delinking from data source). For some reason, codes i tried just have overwritten previous chart instead of copying each chart. Here is partially working code. Thanks for your help:

```
Option Explicit

Dim pptApp As Object ' PowerPoint Application
Dim pptPres As Object ' PowerPoint Presentation
Dim pptSlide As Object ' PowerPoint Slide
Dim ministryName As String ' Name of the ministry from cell H3
Dim currentDate As String ' Current date

Sub CopyChartToPowerPoint2()
    Dim chartObject As chartObject ' ChartObject in Excel
    Dim pptShape As Object ' PowerPoint Shape
    Const ppPasteOLEObject As Integer = 0
    Const ppLayoutTitleOnly As Integer = 11
    
    ' Set the ministry name and current date
    ministryName = Sheets("Tile with chart").Range("H3").Value
    currentDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    ' Open or activate PowerPoint
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Create a new presentation or activate an existing one
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations(ministryName & " " & currentDate & ".pptx")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
        pptPres.SaveAs ministryName & " " & currentDate & ".pptx"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Add a new slide or activate an existing slide
    If pptPres.Slides.Count = 0 Then
        Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    Else
        Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    End If
    
    ' Clear existing shapes from the slide
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        pptShape.Delete
    Next pptShape
    
    ' Copy the chart and paste it into the slide
    Set chartObject = Sheets("Tile with chart").ChartObjects("Chart 5")
    chartObject.Copy
    Set pptShape = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject)(1)
    
    ' Adjust the position of the pasted chart
    pptShape.Left = 50 ' Adjust left position
    pptShape.Top = 100 ' Adjust top position
    
    ' Delink the chart from its source data
    pptShape.LinkFormat.BreakLink
    
    ' Save and show the presentation
    pptPres.Save
    pptPres.Windows(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to loop through the list of ministries AND through the KPIs, and for each of those create a chart that has to be inserted in the ppt, correct? Where are theit full lists?

Comment: @Bradipo Thanks. User will select a ministry from the drop down menu. Then user will click a button to go through all KPIs, generate chart and copy that chart into PPT.

Comment: @Bradipo I am not sure about this question "Where are theit full lists?". In terms of set up H3 has drop down with list of ministries. I3 has list of KPIs that corresponds to each ministry (that list is generated from another list in =$M$2#. put "#" there so list updates for each ministry (dynamic). Not sure if that helps. Also, there is only 1 chart (Chart 5) that is updated automatically every time new KPI is selected. I had codes that partially worked, but every time it pasted new chart into ppt, somehow numbers got screwed up and all charts ended up having same numbers as last KPI. Thanks!